# Not working {% csrf_token %}

Tags: python, django, csrf

Django 1.9.5
CSRF token not adding hidden form field. Trying render_to_request with RequestContext, just render, trying decorator - nothing works, hidden input dont shows

home.html

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#encrypt").click(function () {
        var postData = {
            text: $("#input-box").val(),
            rotate: $("#rotate").val()
        };
        $.post('/encrypt', postData, function (out){
            alert(out)
        });
    });
});
  </script>
<form name="ciepher" method="POST" action="">
          {% csrf_token %}
 <!-- form code-->
</form>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, render
from django.template import RequestContext
from caesar import models

def home(request):
    return render_to_response("home.html")

def encrypt(request):
    input_text = request.POST["text"]
    rotate = request.POST["rotate"]
    output_text = models.encode(input_text, rotate)
    frequency = models.get_frequency(input_text)
    #return render_to_response("home.html", {'input_text': input_text, 'rotate': rotate, 'output_text': output_text, 'frequency': frequency}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
    return render(request,"home.html", {'input_text': input_text, 'rotate': rotate, 'output_text': output_text, 'frequency': frequency})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not passing [`RequestContext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext) with [`render_to_response()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response). Modify the code to something like this:

```
def home(request):
    return render_to_response("home.html", context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Or you can just use the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut:

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, "home.html")
```

Comment: Oh, such an easy mistake, and took so much time. Many thanks, its work!

Comment: Definitely use the `render` shortcut